# How to get data from class into intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

This is my `Post.kt` class

```
data class Post ( val id: Int, val name: String?, val slug: String?,
                  val image: String?, val body: String?, val icon: String?,
                  val quote: String?, val video: String?, val created_at: String?,
                  val updated_at: String?
)
```

I need to get `val slug` in my adapter intent so i can send it to other activity

`Adapter`

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var textView: TextView
        var aImage: ImageView

        init {
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name)
            aImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_image)


            aImage.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                    val intent = Intent(aImage.context, ArticlesDetail::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("my_slug",text_slug.text.toString()) //here
                    aImage.context.startActivity(intent)

                    Log.e("Click", "you click on = $adapterPosition")

                }

            })

        }
    }
```

> **Note:** `text_slug.text.toString()` doesn't exist it's just a placeholder, i need to provide my `val slug` instead of `text_slug`. That is what i'm looking for.

Any idea?

## Update

my adapter full code + answer below included

```
class MyPostsRecyclerViewAdapter(val posts : ArrayList<Post>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyPostsRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_posts, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return posts.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textView.text = posts.get(position).name
        holder.bind(this.posts[position]) //added

        Glide.with(holder.aImage.context)
            .load(posts.get(position).image)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder2)
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder2)
            .fallback(R.drawable.placeholder2)
            .into(holder.aImage)
    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var textView: TextView
        var aImage: ImageView

        init {
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name)
            aImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_image)
        }
        // added
        fun bind(post:Post){
            textView.text = post.slug?:""
            aImage.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                    val intent = Intent(aImage.context, ArticlesDetail::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("my_slug",post.slug?:"") // <<---
                    aImage.context.startActivity(intent)

                    Log.d("my slug is:", post.slug)

                    Log.e("Click", "you click on = $adapterPosition")

                }
            })
        }
    }

}
```

> Result of this code was app crashed (closed with this error
>   `my.app.name has stopped`)

## Update 2

This is my destination activity `ArticlesDetail` code.

**Explanation**
The slug that i sent by my intent code above comes to this activity and get data from api link based on that slug.

```
class ArticlesDetail : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.article_details)

        callAPIDemo()
    }

    // api code
    private fun callAPIDemo() {
        val mySlugValue: String = intent.getStringExtra("my_slug")
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "https://example.com/api/articles/$mySlugValue"

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->

                val list: ArrayList<Post> = ArrayList()
                getPosts(response,list)

                // here you will have the complete list of data in your "list" variable
                posts_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                Log.d("my list", list.toString())
                posts_list.adapter = ArticlesAdapter(list)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            })
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }


    fun getPosts(response: String,list:ArrayList<Post>) {

        var jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
        val jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts")

        for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
            val jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
            var listingObject = Post(
                jsonObject1.getInt("id"),
                jsonObject1.getString("name"),
                jsonObject1.getString("slug"),
                jsonObject1.getString("image"),
                jsonObject1.getString("body"),
                jsonObject1.getString("icon"),
                jsonObject1.getString("quote"),
                jsonObject1.getString("video"),
                jsonObject1.getString("created_at"),
                jsonObject1.getString("updated_at")

            )
            list.add(listingObject)

        }
    }
}
```

currently when i click on image that supposed to bring me to this activity along with slug value i get this error

> at
>   my.app.name.ui.ArticlesDetail.ArticlesDetail.getPosts(ArticlesDetail.kt:73)

Line 73 is this line:

```
val jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts")
```

Comment: implement Parcelable in  Post class and sen data as 
intent.putExtra("user", Parcel OBJECT);
and get
getIntent().getParcelableExtra("")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting list in your ViewHolder Class you will have to first put **inner** keyword before class, like below (Based on your old approach)

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var textView: TextView
        var aImage: ImageView

        init {
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name)
            aImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_image)



    aImage.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            val intent = Intent(aImage.context, ArticlesDetail::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("my_slug",posts.get(adapterPosition).slug) // <<--- added here
            aImage.context.startActivity(intent)

            Log.e("Click", "you click on = $adapterPosition")

        }

    })
        }
```

Comment: `posts.get` get part is red

Comment: did you put inner keyword?

Comment: which part is inner keyword?

Comment: `inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {`

Comment: same error happens that i explained after my second update

Comment: at my.app.name.ui.ArticlesDetail.ArticlesDetail.getPosts(ArticlesDetail.kt:73)

Comment: can you post your logcat here

Comment: logcat prints nothing, this error is in run tab, wait i will post it

Comment: ok your code works now, i had to comment all codes in my destination activity `the error is about data parsing` apparently must use different approach.

Comment: @mafortis As per the screenshot you shared  Its different error its happening in your ArticlesDetail class.

Comment: exactly, i just realized that by commenting my api function in destination activity, i'll create new post for that.

Comment: bro i made new question with full details would you mind to check it out please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166518/get-json-object-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the `setOnClickListener` to the method where you receive the data from the adapter:

Something like this:

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var textView: TextView
    var aImage: ImageView

    init {
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name)
        aImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_image)
    }

    fun bind(post:Post){
        textView.text = post.slug?:""
        aImage.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                val intent = Intent(aImage.context, ArticlesDetail::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("my_slug",post.slug?:"") // <<---
                aImage.context.startActivity(intent)

                Log.e("Click", "you click on = $adapterPosition")

            }
        })
    }
}
```

//ADAPTER (Basic)

```
class PostAdapter(val postList:List<Post>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.post_view, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view, listener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return postList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(this.postList[position])
    }
}
```

**//UPDATED** Based on user post update:

First of all , I recommend you to have different files. One for Adapter, and another for ViewHolder, take care, I renamed it.

Also,  try to bind all the info of the view inside it's method (in this case `bind(post:View)`

```
class MyPostsRecyclerViewAdapter(val posts : ArrayList<Post>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder {
        val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_posts, parent, false)
        return PostViewHolder(view,parent.context)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return posts.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(this.posts[position]) //added
    }
}

class PostViewHolder(itemView: View,val context:Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var textView: TextView
    var aImage: ImageView

    init {
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name)
        aImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.a_image)
    }
    // added
    fun bind(post:Post){

        textView.text = post.name?:""

        Glide.with(context)
        .load(post.image?:"")
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder2)
        .error(R.drawable.placeholder2)
        .fallback(R.drawable.placeholder2)
        .into(aImage)

        aImage.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                val intent = Intent(context, ArticlesDetail::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("my_slug",post.slug?:"") // <<---
                context.startActivity(intent)

                Log.d("my slug is:", post.slug)

                //Log.e("Click", "you click on = $adapterPosition") --> for this log, you need to pass also the position

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume this viewholder is used in a recycler view, so remember in adapter to call this method when called. (modified a little bit answerr)

Comment: One thing should be updated, this method `setOnClickListener` should be added to `init` body, you should not set it each time in bind method. Keep instance of your `post` (like `lateinit var post` and in bind `this.post = post`.

Comment: ok the first code failed, let me try your update. i'll inform you of the result

Comment: @mafortis also try to update your post, with your adapter, so we can see/help what's going

Comment: updated my question please check if i did something wrong

Comment: @Shudy I have updated my code again with more info i think this should help you get the issue

Comment: @mafortis,Edited my answer. But the error you are getting now, is not about the adapter/viewholder. You hace to check what is going with the parsing . I recommend you to open a different post to check this error. But print the json respone you get. Be sure that exist the tag post inside de response.. etc..

Comment: ok, i try this if i could print slug in my destination activity then we're good to go for this question.